# How to stop cross site scripting in Joomla 2.5?

Tags: php, joomla

I need a help on Cross Side Scripting(XSS). I want when anyone enter Preg character it simply gets remove from the search text box in front page.

In current setting it only removes few chracter that are only related to HTML tags like `<>,#` etc. But i need these set of characters:

```
< > ( ) ' " / \ *; = { } ` (back tick) % + ^! - \x00-\x20 (x is hexadecimal notation) [Includes Space, Tab, Carriage Return, Line Feed]
```

should get removed when user insert it in any text box like search module of Joomla front end etc. I am using Joomla 2.5

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So what have you tried to solve the problem? -1 for no research effort.

Comment: @sachleen if i have solution i can solve it by my own. I do not need to come here. Moreover if you have solution you can let me know. You do not have right to turn down someone. This is not anyone personal property. Sir, This is community to serve people not to let feel.

Comment: Are you looking at smart search or basic search? JFilterInput is what you would want to use.  If you find a way to actually do xss from there you should send it to security@joomla.org.

Comment: @Elin i just want special user will not able to search with special character. I am some what able to do it with some core programing. But i was looking for some plugin if anyone knows or any code.

Comment: You know that Joomla sanitizes these right? There are some real consequences to not allowing people to search for valid phrases.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean a specific individual or someone in the Special group?
Are you using the input filter settings in global configuration?

Comment: something like that i have checked Joomla configuration settings in text filters under public user it filters only HTML tags like #,., > and <. But i need some other character in this.